# Generating java swing fields based on user input

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane

Java beginner here.

I am trying to generate Labels based on user input(take input for the number of labels to generate between 0 to 50) in a JPanel inside a JScrollPane.

The labels are generating correctly but the problem is the panel cant be scrolled down to view all the Labels.

Is it because I am using absolute layout for the panel? If yes then what might be the solution? Please guide.

Note: I made the labels using an array of 50 JLabels in a for loop. Terrible programming practice maybe but works.

Here's the code snippet

```
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(800, 800);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrollPane.setBounds(103, 37, 439, 350);
        frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        scrollPane.setViewportView(panel);
        panel.setLayout(null);

        JButton btnGenerateLabels = new JButton("Generate Labels");
        btnGenerateLabels.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JLabel[] lab =  new JLabel[50];
                int  y = 50;
                for(int i=0; i<50; i++)
                {
                    lab[i] = new JLabel();
                    lab[i].setText("Label "+(i+1));
                    panel.add(lab[i]);
                    lab[i].setBounds(180, y, 97, 25);
                    y += 30;
                }
            }
        });
        btnGenerateLabels.setBounds(129, 23, 152, 25);
        panel.add(btnGenerateLabels);
```

Comment: Instead of `panel.setLayout(null);` you should/could probably use `panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));`, and that *could* already solve the problem.

Comment: My guess is that your `JPanel` is not set to a size larger than your viewport, so there's no extra space to scroll around in. Try that. I'm purely shooting from the hip, but I've been around Swing enough to guess.

Comment: No. None worked. The gridlayout didn't go with the setbounds for my labels. And the size increment didn't happen to have any effect on the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it because I am using absolute layout for the panel?

Yes. Don't use a null layout. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers.

The solution is to use a layout manager, probably the GridLayout as was suggested.

After all the components have been added to the panel you then need to invoke `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on the panel. This will invoke the layout manager and each component will be given a size/location.

Scrollbars will then appear as required.

Comment: Ok it worked. I was not aware about the revalidate() and the layout used was GridLayout as suggested by @Marco13 Thanks for the help.